# Can you restrict the max bbox or tile size for WMS request in geoserver

Tags: geoserver

I have a dataset that must contain a watermark that covers a percentage of a rendered image to meet a licensing issue and I'm struggling to ensure this.

Geoserver does not allow me to get it to scale the watermark appropriately (happy to be proven wrong), so the coverage of the watermark is dependant on the size of image requested.  As a work around I hoped I could get the WMS to reject requests that have a bbox larger than a max size suitable for the watermark image, does anyone know of a way to do this out of the box?

While I can set the tile size in our client to match there is nothing someone accessing the WMS directly.

While I'm a java developer by trade I'd much rather I could do this using an existing feature without having to resort to intercepting the requests or modifying geoserver, so if anyone has any suggestions I'd love to hear them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're correct, it's not possible to configure in the GUI.  If you were using MapServer you could I think do this using the MAXSIZE parameter which inserts MaxWidth and 
MaxHeight elements in the GetCapabilities response like below:

```
    </ContactInformation>
    <Fees>none</Fees>
    <AccessConstraints>
    This service is for non-commercial use only. Neither...
    </AccessConstraints>
    <MaxWidth>3072</MaxWidth>
    <MaxHeight>3072</MaxHeight>
</Service>
<Capability>
```

You could perhaps try adding these elements and suitable values in the XML files created under the hood by the GeoServer GUI, but I don't know if GeoServer would honour them

Answer (score 0):

Have you taken a look at [WMS Decorations](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/advanced/wmsdecoration.html)?  This would allow you to place a dynamically resizing image with a watermark style opacity.  You'd still have to figure out some way to force the format_options request parameter to be sent, perhaps a small query rewrite on the server to force adding it onto the end of all requests?